# Email Regex that allows for white space?

Tags: c#, javascript, regex, asp.net-mvc-4

The [Email] attribute in Asp.Net MVC4 does not allow white space on the client side, does anyone know how i can allow something like "   myemail@email.com  " to pass through the unobtrusive java script generated by the property decorators?

When it hits Http Post, i can trim() the model.Email before doing anything with it. I just need to get past client validation.

I'm guessing any valid email regex will work if i tack on \s* at the start and end of the pattern?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried this ? http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery to trim the textbox value. Something like:

```
$("#textboxId").on("change", function () {
   $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok i guess i shouldved tested it before posting, but yes you can tack on a \s* so that ignores whitespace..heres the regex i ended up using

```
    [RegularExpression(@"^(\s*[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9}\s*)$")]
```

Comment: This is [not a valid regex for emails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address). Or, more to the point, it is extremely simplistic and will match only a tiny subset of valid email addresses.